# Mysqli returns the wrong data

Tags: php, mysqli

I would like to echo out the values of the column **username** and tried it like this:

```
public function username_exists($username) {
    $conn = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db_name);
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT username FROM fe_users WHERE username = $username");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row["username"];
    }
}
```

When I run this code, for some reason it always returns the string **33**, which is also stored in my database but it is definitely not the value of the column *username*. Why am I getting this output and how can I display the username which is stored in the table *fe_users*?

Comment: 1) Strings such as $username need to be quoted 2) You're code is open for SQL injection. Take advantage of mysqli's features, and use parameter binding. Then you won't need to worry about quoting your variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quotes around `$username`

```
SELECT username FROM fe_users WHERE username = '$username'"
```

Better use bind and prepare statement. It automatically escape your string and free from sql injection attack

```
/* prepare statement */
$stmt = $conn->prepare( "SELECT username FROM fe_users WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($col1);

/* fetch values */
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    printf("%s %s\n", $col1);
}

/* close statement */
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Thank you but when I use your code I get this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Comment: after prepare `if ( false===$stmt ) {
 
  die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
}` to check error

Comment: $stmt is already true. I only had to remove `$conn` from the first parameter of your first line. It works great now. Thank you so much!